# JPA Hibernate Configuration Errors

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, ejb

I want to enable JPA for an EJB module, in an IntelliJ J2E project. I don't have an existing database schema to import; I want to generate the schema and tables from my EJB POJO class. I then want to generate ORM mappings.

I've enabled JavaEE Persistence framework support in IntelliJ, with Hibernate as the provider. I've updated persistence.xml and assigned MySQL@localhost as the data source, to the JPA persistence unit. I've also added the JPA descriptor to the ear artifact.

When I try to add the JPA annotations to my POJO, e.g. @Table, @Column etc, I get an error "Cannot resolve table 'TABLE_NAME'"...same applies for columns. The context action I get is 'Assign Data Sources', but the data source is showing as assigned to the persistence unit.

I've run the code and now just get a huge stack trace.

The tutorials i've found are either for importing an existing schema (which I don't have), or use other IDEs. My persistence.xml and one of my pojos are included below

Thanks in advance..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySQL"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***"/>

            <!--Hibernate properties-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATALOG_ITEM")
public class CatalogItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATALOG_ITEM_ID")
    private Long itemID;
    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String description;
    private Date availableDate;

    public CatalogItem() {

    }
```

GlassFish Log

```
[2020-05-29 12:56:46,830] Artifact jpa:ear: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2020-05-29 12:56:46,830] Artifact jpa:ear: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory. Please see server.log for more details.
Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
[PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Server Log

```
[2020-05-29T00:56:46.782+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1590710206782] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:901)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1314)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1240)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:901)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:217)
  RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]

  RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]

  RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]]

  HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]

    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:128)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl could not locate TransactionManager to suspend any current transaction; base JtaPlatform impl (org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform@45dad759)?
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    ... 56 more
]]

[2020-05-29T00:56:46.784+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1590710206784] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app]]

[2020-05-29T00:56:46.784+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1590710206784] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:901)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1314)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1240)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:901)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:128)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl could not locate TransactionManager to suspend any current transaction; base JtaPlatform impl (org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform@45dad759)?
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    ... 56 more
]]

[2020-05-29T00:56:46.812+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1590710206812] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app : [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: NewPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1314)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1240)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:901)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:128)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:901)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl could not locate TransactionManager to suspend any current transaction; base JtaPlatform impl (org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform@45dad759)?
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    ... 56 more
]]
```

Comment: You get an expected warning from the inspection that checks your annotations against the configured database. Since the database is empty, the tables cannot be resolved and IDE reports exactly that. You can disable the inspection if it annoys you until you create the schema.

Comment: thanks @CrazyCoder. so how do i generate the schema from the class entities? i thought that's what the hbm2ddl.auto property did, but when i run the program, nothing happens. it's proving harder than i expected, to find setup tutorials for jpa on intellij. they're either maven, or spring, or eclipse

Comment: It's a feature of Hibernate, not IntelliJ IDEA. Do a research how Hibernate creates schema for you. Here is [an example](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hbm2ddl-auto-example-hibernate-xml-config.html).

Comment: thanks @CrazyCoder. had a look through the docs and made some further updates to persistence.xml. i've also added the jpa descriptor to the ear file, which i deploy to a glassfish server. i now get a huge stack trace when trying to compile my app. i've added the stack trace and updated persistence.xml to the code block